# Problem with Jack Audio Server

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, audio-jack

I use Ubuntu-Studio 22-04-2 LTS (64 bit machine), with Jack Audio Connections Kit to handle all the internal and external audio used in the PC.

I don't know why but, since the last system upgrading (2 days ago) the "DEFAULT SINK" and "DEFAULT SOURCE" items don't appear selected as the "STANDARD" Jack connections (JACK SINK and JACK SOURCE), as it is expected each time the system is started.

I don't have any idea about how to fix this because I saw into the QJACKCTL app and all the options are as it is supposed to be, including the starting script:

"pacmd set-default-sink jack_out && pacmd set-default-source jack_in"

So... What is wrong here?

How can I fix it?